# Advice on structuring data for scalability with large number of nested objects

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Looking for advice on how best to structure data in MongoDB, particularly for scalability - worried about having an array of potentially thousands of objects within each user object.

I am building a language learning app with a built in flashcard system. I want users to 'unlock' new vocabulary for each level, which automatically gets added to their flashcards, so when you unlock level 4, all the vocabulary attached to level 4 gets added to your flashcards.

For the flashcards themselves, I want a changable 'due date', so that you get prompted to do certain cards at a certain date - if you're familiar with spaced repition, that's the plan. So when you get a card, you can say how well you know it and, for example, if you know it well you won't get it for another week, but if you get it wrong you'll get it again the next day.

I'm using MongoDB for the backend, but am a little unsure about how best to structure my data. Currently, I have two objects: one for the cards, and one for the users.

The cards object looks like this, so there's a nested object for each flashcard, with a unique ID, the level the word appears in, and then the word in both languages.

```
  const CardsList = [
    {
      id: 1,
      level: 1,
      gd: "sgìth",
      en: "tired",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      level: 2,
      gd: "ceist",
      en: "question",
    },
  ];
```

Then each user has an object like the below, with various user data, and a nested array of objects for the cards - with the id of every card they've unlocked, and the date at which that card is next due.

```
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "gordon",
      level: 2,
      cards: [
        { id: 1, date: "07/12/2021" },
        { id: 2, date: "09/12/2021" },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "mike",
      level: 1,
      cards: [
        { id: 1, date: "08/12/2021" },
        { id: 2, date: "07/12/2021" },
      ],
    },
```

This works fine, but I'm a bit concerned about the scalability of it.

The plan is to have about two or three thousand words in total, and so if I had, say, fifty users complete the app, then that would mean fifty user objects, each with as much as three thousand objects in that nested cards array.

Is that going to be a problem? Would it be a problem if I had a thousand (or more) users, instead of 50? Is there a more sensible way of structuring the data that I'm not spotting?

Comment: (1) Number of users 50 or 50,000 or more is not a problem. (2) The nested data `cards` array for each user - needs to be a finite/known number - can have 3000 or 10,000 elements. (3) Each document (record) can be upto 16 Mega Bytes (MB) maximum size - this allows large sized documents with large nested/array fields. Also, see [Data Modeling Introduction](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/).

Comment: Thank you @prasad_, that's helpful - so as long as the records are below 16mb, which they should be since they're just dates and IDs, it should be fine?

Comment: You can possibly figure the estimated size of the data, by creating some sample data.  A document size can be found using the [$bsonSize](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bsonSize/).